# How do I open multiple files as part of gVim's launch procedure?

Tags: vim, gvim, user-profiles, application-launch, gvimrc

I use gVim a lot in Windows at work to edit text files. I want $VIMRC to *always* be in buffer 1, and my vim_cheatsheet to *always* be in buffer 2. I tried putting "e $VIMRC" in my .vimrc, which didn't work. Google has been less than helpful. Having to open a terminal to launch is exactly *not* what I want. I want my vim to know to always put those to files in those two buffers. Any suggestions?

Comment: `:s/\$VIMRC/$MYVIMRC`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putting the `:edit` command(s) into your `~/.vimrc` doesn't work because its sourcing happens too early. But you can delay the opening via `:autocmd`:

```
:autocmd VimEnter * edit $MYVIMRC
:autocmd VimEnter * split path/to/vim_cheatsheet
```

Above makes the files also visible in windows; I'm not sure you would want that. If you just need to define the buffers (without loading or displaying them in a window yet), you can use `:badd`:

```
:badd $MYVIMRC
:badd path/to/vim_cheatsheet
```

Comment: Great! And it looks like it doesn't add fresh copies everytime I reload, so perfect! Thanks!